# How to extract a portion of a file over multiple lines in python?

Tags: python

I am new to Python, and I'm having a difficult time understanding the syntax.

I have a very large file in which I need to extract a certain portion of it to a new file. How would I go about doing this? I was doing a little research, and I think what I have so far is that I would need to extract each line of my file as a string, then I would need to extract a a substring from inside said string. I'm not sure if that is right, but any guidance would be GREATLY appreciated.

For instance, the file may look something like this....

```
Test file number one two three
test file number two three four
test file number three four five
```

And I would need to extract for example the third and fourth word in each line.

So I would need the output to look like.....

```
number one
number two
number three
```

I would really appreciate your help. I am extremely new to the Python language but have a project that needs to be completed.Thank you in advance.

Comment: SO isn't a code writing service, though we are happy to help those who have shown significant effort. What have you already tried?

Comment: All I had so far was 

    #!/user/bin/env python
    file = open("location\\filename","r+")

s = s.replace('w',' ')

chmod +x code.py

Answer (score 2):

For each line in the file:

```
print(" ".join(line.split(" ")[2:3])
```

where `line` is the variable in which you store the lines that you read in, and the numbers between the [] refer to which words you want to select (remember Python, like almost all other languages, count from 0). If you wanted to add more words, you would do it like so:

```
print(" ".join(line.split(" ")[2:5])
```

and so on.

Here's how I would implement it:

```
with open("file.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        print(" ".join(line.split(" ")[2:3])
```

As far as writing this to a file goes, the fastest way to do this would be to pipe the output of this script to a file using your operating system's shell:

```
python3 this_script.py > output.txt
```

Thanks Roman Tsegelskyi for the suggestion regarding the call to `print()`.

Comment: `print(" ".join(line.split(" ")[2:3])` as slightly shorted way to write it